# Why this high-pass filter behaves like a low-pass filter for high frequencies, on this ideal LTSpice simulation?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, bode-plot, active-filter

I am simulating the usual active, first-order high-pass filter on LTSpice, as below:

[image: Circuit]

The Op-Amp I'm using is the following:

[image: OpAmp]

This is the simulation result:

[image: Graph]

### What is the explanation for the behavior above 100 kHz?

The gain starts to fall, and the phase also falls...

Comment: What op-amp are you using? Only high performance and RF op-amps can handle 100KHZ+ with ease.

Comment: That is not distortion, merely high-frequency rolloff.

Comment: Yes, there is a limit to the maximum operating frequency of an amplifier, the "single pole" part of the opamp puts a limit of the maximum frequency the amp can handle (much like a real amp)

Comment: And - please, realize that "distortion" is not the right term. Distortion is caused by a non-linearity of the transfer characteristic (time domain).

Comment: Ths is a passive filter followed by a buffer, not an active filter.

Comment: @LvW thank you (and uint128_t), I didn't know that. I fixed the title and removed the "distortion" tag. Hopefully this was the reason for the downvote, since I don't see any other issues with the question. Can my question be further improved?

Comment: @EJP can you elaborate further? I would like to know more, since this exact circuit topology is mentioned as an active filter in my book by Nilsson & Riedel, chapter 15 - "Active Filters".

Comment: Of course, it is an active filter. There is no buffer at all. Instead, the opamp is wired as a "differentiator with loss" - which is identical to a first order (inverting) highpass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an ideal "single pole" operational amplifier.

A single pole amplifier is an amplifier with a first order low-pass characteristic. The pole determines the corner frequency of the pole. For a real opamp it can be found using the gain-bandwidth product, which is the product of open loop gain and the corner-frequency.

Above 100kHz you see the typical characteristic of a low-pass. A gain roll-off of 20dB/decade and a phase shift of -90 degrees.

Since you are using an ideal opamp it should be possible to set the corner (pole) frequency to a higher value, so that it doesn't affect your transfer function.

Comment: Great answer. Indeed I was able to configure the op-amp and set that corner frequency to a higher value. Excellent. I learned a lot.